# Uniform approximation of probability of closed set with tight family

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $(\mu_\theta)_{\theta \in \Theta}$ be a uniformly tight family of probability measures indexed by some set $\Theta$ on a complete metric space $S$, i.e. for every $\varepsilon > 0$ there exists a compact subset $K$ of $S$ such that 
$$
\sup_{\theta \in \Theta} \mu_\theta(K) \geq 1- \varepsilon.
$$

If $F$ is a closed set in $S$, can we then find a decreasing sequence of closed sets $(F_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ that are strict supersets of $F$ so that 
$$
\sup_{\theta \in \Theta} |\mu_{\theta}(F_n) - \mu_\theta(F) | \to 0
$$
as $n \to \infty$?

Comment: What type of sets are the $F_n$'s? Why don't you take $F_n=F$ for all $n$?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I have updated the question. I need to approximate $F$ with strict supersets unfortunately. I wanted to use $F_n = \{x \in S | d(x, F) \leq 1/n\}$ but I don't think that works.